# Apagando colunas que contenham NA´s em suas ultimas 5 linhas

Tags: r

Tenho esse dataframe pessoal,

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:50, B = 11:60, c = 21:70)
head(df)
df.final <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))
```

Eu quero apagar as colunas que nos seus ultimos 5 valores (linha 46 até linha 50) contenham pelo menos 1 valor NA.

Bom, tenho usado muito o `dplyr`. Consigo fazer isso com ele?

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando o `dplyr`:

```
df.final %>% 
  select_if(colSums(is.na(tail(., 5))) == 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma das soluções seria:

```
lims <- c(46, 50)

keep <- lapply(df[1:ncol(df)], function(x) sum(is.na(x[lims[1]:lims[2]])) == 0  )

keep <- unlist(keep)

df <- df[,keep]

tail(df)
```